# ratchet as a mobile web solution

Tags: mobile-website, ratchet-bootstrap

So I'd like to use ratchet to create a mobile web experience (and not a phone gap/hybrid app experience), and ratchet seems like a good fit for that.  However, I don't want the functionality to be broken if a user views my prototype from a desktop browser (it can be ugly ).  I've noticed that some of the javascript like the modals don't work in a desktop and only on the mobile device.

What's the work around to get something like the modal working on a desktop browser as well?

I noticed in the js file that I can just add the same event listener to the click event from the touched event like so:

```
  window.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    var modal = getModal(event);
    if (modal) {
      if (modal && modal.classList.contains('modal')) {
        modal.classList.toggle('active');
      }
      event.preventDefault(); // prevents rewriting url (apps can still use hash values in url)
    }
  });
```

Any suggestions on doing a side by side with say bootstrap?  Is that feasible?

Comment: Hey, what did you end up using?

Comment: I ended up just using ionic to create the experience and then copying chunks of code out of that to fit the mobile we experience